# Flask SQLAlchemy updating user information in DRY code

Tags: python, database, object, flask, sqlalchemy

Currently using Flask and SQLAlchemy, but relatively new to Python. Say I have a function that takes in user information as an object, and then check to see if we have this user on file in database.

```
user_information = { "first_name": "John", "last_name": "Doe", "phone_number": "123-456-7890", "address": "555 Pine street", "favorite_food": "" }
user_record = flask.g.db.session.query(User).filter_by(first_name=user_information["first_name"]).first()
```

If say the user_record comes back as

```
user_record = User("first_name": "John", "last_name": "Doe", "phone_number": "098-765-4321", "address": "", "favorite_food": "pizza")
```

Note that phone_number has changed, our record didn't have address on file, the new input data doesn't have a favorite food.

My question is, how do I cleanly ensure that we update our user database to have the latest phone number, update the address if we previously didn't have any data, ignore the new favorite food since we prefer to have old data. I'm aware I can simply create a new object with a ton of if/else to pick and choose for every key/value and save that to the database, but would not be DRY especially if we have like 30 columns for user. Does db.merge already handle this, or are there some nifty shorthand tricks in Python to create an updated user object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your question statement it sounds like you don't know any IDs, but there are some columns - maybe first and last name - that together are unique. You could then have the following:

```py
class User(db.Model):
  @classmethod
  def create_or_update(cls, fields, identifiers):
    # Remove all empty fields - you could potentially also early return here
    # if there are no filled fields at all
    filled_fields = {k: v for k, v in identifiers.items() if v != "" and v is not None}

    match = cls.objects.filter(**identifiers).one_or_none()
    if match:
      # Object exists, update its values
      for key, value in filled_fields.items():
        setattr(match, key, value)
    else:
      # Object does not exist, create it
      new_object = cls(**identifiers, **filled_fields)
      db.session.add(new_object)
    db.session.commit()
    return match

user_information = { "phone_number": "123-456-7890", "address": "555 Pine street", "favorite_food": "" }
identifiers = { "first_name": "John", "last_name": "Doe" }
User.create_or_update(user_information, identifiers)
```

Some pointers:

- `one_or_none` gives an error if more than one record matches
- `setattr` can be used to set a variable whose name is variable, like `some_dict[some_key]`
- Remember to `commit` your changes
- There is no harm in overwriting fields if their value is the same

If you're using PostgreSQL however, and like to get closer to the metal, have a look at `INSERT ON CONFLICT UPDATE` (also known as UPSERT). It means that if a record is entered that conflicts with some unique constraints (like first + last name), then the existing row is taken and the new values are assigned there. It essentially does all this for you!